# Invalid keystore format using java

Tags: java, keystore

I'm trying to make a post request to one of our clients with certificate as part of their security.

I tried testing it in postman, just like the usual attached the certificate on postman settings and then able to make a post request to their api.

Now my problem is i'm encountering this error when i'm doing the request on our platform built in java

java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:664)
java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)

On the test environment they don't require the password hence null.

```
    try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(p12Cert))
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        keyStore.load(inputStream, null);
```

I traced the engineLoad method from javakeystore.

```
private static final int MAGIC = 0xfeedfeed;
private static final int VERSION_1 = 0x01;
private static final int VERSION_2 = 0x02;
        if (xMagic!=MAGIC ||
            (xVersion!=VERSION_1 && xVersion!=VERSION_2)) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid keystore format");
        }
```

Can someone elaborate the above?

Comment: Your sample code isn't giving enough information to identify the problem. What is the `p12Cert` in line 1?

Comment: byte[] p12Cert = Base64.decodeBase64(jksData);
jksData is encoded in base64 p12cert.

Comment: found the solution now thanks for trying cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Able to fix the problem above, first is the p12 cert i am trying to encode in base64 is in utf-8 encoding which is wrong and should be converted from HEXADECIMAL to base64.